# Laravel blade for loop submits first form item with Jquery AJAX but for others gives error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

So my view displays products in a card view, where each card has a add to cart button that submits a form through AJAX JQuery. The product cards are populated on the page through a blade for loop. However, it only lets me add the first product to the cart. For all the other ones it gives the following error:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.
```

I have pasted my blade code which includes the jquery here so its easier to read: https://mystb.in/BerlinTeamsAffiliated.php-template

My `TestController.php` where the form posts to:

```
public function test(Request $request, Product $product){
    return response()->json([
    'success' => true,
    'message' => 'Data inserted successfully ' . $request->name. ' '.$product->name]);
    }
```

The `web.php` file routes:

```
Route::get('/test', 'TestController@showTest');
Route::post('/test/{product}', 'TestController@test');
```

Note: The laravel stack trace shows the correct form being submitted through the request body, but it just gives that error.

Comment: How you call this POST method from your blade? Edit and attach your blade form code. The problem is on your blade code

Comment: I added it to the question. But here is the link https://mystb.in/BerlinTeamsAffiliated.php-template @sta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML id attribute name has to be unique. Since this line

```
<input type="hidden" name="product_id" id="product_id" value={{ $p->id }}>
```

is part of a `@foreach`, the `id="product_id"` name isn't unique.

The url your are using in the ajax call is formed like this:

```
var product_id = $("#product_id").val();
var url = '/test/' + product_id;
```

As a result, the value `product_id` is empty in all cases (except the first one) and the url will be `/test` (without the product id), which is, coincidentally, defined as a GET route.

You can try to resolve this by creating a method that will post your form, with the `product_id` as parameter, and call this method when you click the submit button.

Comment: Yeah thanks a lot for your response i managed to figure it out. I had to pass like this to my form. `<form action="{{ route('my.form', $p->id) }}">`

Comment: That'll work as well, but you don't mind that this will not post your form with ajax?

Comment: It does post it? The items are being added to the cart